# Spring @Autowired object is null

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spock

I'm writing a specification class in spock framework.

```
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = [MyServiceImplementation.class])
    class MyServiceSpecification extends Specification {

         @Autowired
         private MyService myServiceImplementation

         def "  " {
             //code
         }
    }
```

The class `MyServiceImplementation` is annotated `@Service`. I'm not using XML configuration. `MyServiceImpl` is an implementation of the interface: `MyService`.

Why is the autowired object `myServiceImplementation` null?

I tried using `ComponentScan` and it still didn't work.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing 'new' MyServiceSpecification somewhere in your code (or Spock is doing that)!

Comment: Is there any workaround for it?  I can't see how this can affect null value of this field

Comment: Do you use a Spock Spring Module (http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_spring_module)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to have both `spock-core` and `spock-spring` on the classpath. Second, `@ContextConfiguration(classes=` takes a list of configuration classes, not bean classes.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [MyConfig.class])
class MyServiceSpecification extends Specification {

     @Autowired
     private MyService myServiceImplementation

     def "  " {
         //code
     }
}

// You could also define @ComponentScan here
class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    MyService myService() {
      return new MyServiceImplementation();
    }
}
```

Comment: I applied the changes and it worked, thanks for solution